# sql data source used to work in visual studio 2005 but not now in 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2005

I have a sql data source declared on an aspx page which worked fine in Visual Studio 2005, but since migrating to Visual Studio 2010 the DefaultValue parameter is not evaluating the specified function and or the value passed in from a property in the code behind. When checked in SQL Query Analyser the code passed to the database is just using the DafaultValue as a literal string. How can I rectify this?

```
<!--sql data source-->
<asp:SqlDataSource id="sdsltblCNS_SECOND_REF" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SCRConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="Sel_CNS_SECOND_REFByCASite" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue='<%= Common.GetSiteName(Me.SelectedSite) %>' Name="CASite" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

' SelectedSite property
Public ReadOnly Property SelectedSite As Site
    Get
        If ViewState("SelectedSite") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("SelectedSite") = Common.GetSiteByCareID(CareID)
        End If
        Return ViewState("SelectedSite")
    End Get
End Property

-- query analyser
exec Sel_CNS_SECOND_REFByCASite @CASite=N'<%= Common.GetSiteName(Me.SelectedSite) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm stating the obvious and missing something deeper (it's been a long day) but shouldn't you be using a quotation mark versus a single tick, as in:

```
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<%= Common.GetSiteName(Me.SelectedSite) %>" Name="CASite" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" Type="String" />
```